# How to correctly design application architectures on nestjs?

Tags: nestjs

I just started to study my first serious framework with the code itself, there are no problems, but I can’t find examples of how to make the application architecture.

Example - I figured out the related tables in the database, but how to structure it correctly?

conditional example

```
this catalogs

<src>
    <categories>
        <dto>
            create-category.dto.ts
            create-subcategory.dto.ts
        <models>
            category.model.ts
            subcategory.model.ts
        <services>
            category.service.ts
            subcategory.service.ts
        category.controller.ts
        category.module.ts
```

OR

```
<src>
    <categories>
        <dto>
            create-category.dto.ts
        category.model.ts
        category.service.ts
        category.controller.ts
        category.module.ts
    <subcategory>
        <dto>
            create-subcategory.dto.ts
        subcategory.model.ts
        subcategory.service.ts
```

If possible, send me a link where I can read about it at all

Comment: I would add a `modules` folder between `src` and `categories`. I clearly prefer your second choice. But the answer must be opinion-based, so StackOverflow is not the best place. Plus, I would transform `subcategory` => `subcategories`. Lastly, I would put the `subcategories` folder in the `categories` folder.

Answer (score -1):

It's a long story. Basically, (expect CRUDs) an entity doesn't equal a module. Directories you can design whatever you prefer, but you have to focus on defining modules and its boundaries. https://twitter.com/_MaciejSikorski/status/1505613059221594113